# Why can't I use curly brackets in crontab?

Tags: bash, cron

I was recently running a cron job using crontab -e and I found some strange behaviour. The following command doesn't work:

```
 * * * * * cp /home/username/{*txt,*pdf} /home/username/test/
```

but the following does

```
 * * * * * cp /home/username/*txt /home/username/test/
```

while both commands work in bash.

Why am I not able to use curly brackets in cron?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose `cron` uses the `sh` shell to run your commands by default. `sh` does not support  curly-brace wildcards.

IIRC, you can add to your crontab the following line:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```